# Amazon Lambda GET Request, Amazon API Gateway, Empty Query Parameter

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am doing GET request of Amazon API Gateway, I have added following json in mapping template

```
 #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
 {
 "httpMethod": "$context.httpMethod",
 "studentId": $input.json('studentId'),
 "lastName": $input.json('lastName')
 }
```

I am hitting following request

[amazon-lambda-api-link](https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dynamodb/1be6a1f6-e8d8-4394-807e-c3934dcfb46c/Hester)

This API is linked with JAVA lambda function

Here is main class

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler {

    public static Object handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + request.getStudentId() + " , " + request.getLastName());
        Student student = null;
        switch (request.getHttpMethod()) {
            case "POST":
                student = request.getStudent();
                DynamoDbRepository.insertIntoDynamoDB(student);
                return "Successfully inserted into DynamoDB table";
            case "PUT":
                student = request.getStudent();
                DynamoDbRepository.updateStudentDetails(student);
                return "Successfully updated into DynamoDB table";
            case "GET":
                student = DynamoDbRepository.getOneStudentDetails(request.getStudentId(), request.getLastName());
                return student;
            case "DELETE":
                Student delete_student = new Student();
                delete_student.setStudentId(request.getStudentId());
                delete_student.setLastName(request.getLastName());
                DynamoDbRepository.deleteStudentDetails(delete_student);
                return "Successfully deleted into DynamoDB table";
        }
        // TODO: implement your handler
        return null;
    }
}
```

My Request.java class code is: -

```
public class Request {

    private String httpMethod;

    private String studentId;

    private String lastName;

    private Student student;

    public String getHttpMethod() {
        return httpMethod;
    }

    public void setHttpMethod(String httpMethod) {
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }



}
```

The logs which is producing on cloud watch of amazon lambda is

```
    START RequestId: 38ffca9c-c713-47b7-a5fa-af9a894f70ff Version: $LATEST
 org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing connections idle longer than 60000 MILLISECONDS
    Input: , Hester
    Student[studentId]; no HASH key value present: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Student[studentId]; no HASH key value present at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convertKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:329) at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.da
    Student[studentId]; no HASH key value present: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException
    com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Student[studentId]; no HASH key value present
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convertKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:329)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.convertKey(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:310)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:409)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.load(DynamoDBMapper.java:433)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.load(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:85)
        at com.techprimers.serverless.repository.DynamoDbRepository.getOneStudentDetails(DynamoDbRepository.java:31)
        at com.techprimers.serverless.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    END RequestId: 38ffca9c-c713-47b7-a5fa-af9a894f70ff
```

if you can see this line in logs
 "Input: , Hester"

I am printing studentId in main class, but it is showing empty, I can't get it if it's picking 2nd parameter of request why not first parameter?

Comment: I may be lacking some information that will be helpful... are you passing a request body? What does it look like?

Comment: It is simple GET request with query parameters

Generic one
xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dynamodb/{studentId}/{lastName}
 and 
Specific One
xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dynamodb/1be6a1f6-e8d8-4394-807e-c3934dcfb46c/Hester

Answer (score 0):

By changing json in mapping template inside GET method of amazon api gateway

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod",
"studentId":"$input.params('studentId')",
"lastName":"$input.params('lastName')"
}
```

It fixed the error!